# ASP.NET MVC Get id parameter to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use in view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "AcceptStatement", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.StatementID }))
```

in controller:

```
 public ActionResult AcceptStatement(int id)
```

but `id` parameter in controller ends up being a `null` value. How can I get the `id` parameter value into my controller with `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: I don't see that version of BeginForm in the way that you're using it. Make sure you are calling BeginForm correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload of `BeginForm`. You are currently passing the following:

- **actionName:** "Test"
- **controllerName:** "AcceptStatement"
- **routeValues:** "Account"
- **formMethod:** FormMethod.Post
- **htmlAttributes:** `{ id = Model.StatementID }`

This is obviously wrong as it makes no sense. You probably wanted:

```
Html.BeginForm("AcceptStatement", "Account", new { id = Model.StatementID }, FormMethod.Post, null)
```

Using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542(v=vs.118).aspx) overload.

Answer (score 0):

Use the information in [this:](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search)

Basically, your view:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()){    
         <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
        } 
</p>
```

With a Controller of:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString) 
{           
     var movies = from m in db.Movies 
                  select m; 

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
    { 
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)); 
    } 

    return View(movies); 
}
```

---

An alternative to passing the model's value to controller method would be to use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BayID })
```

With your controller method being something like:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
 {
  ...
```

Comment: How does this address the problem?

Comment: Shows the OP how to pass an input/model value to the controller. Quite well, I hope.

Comment: Again, how is that related to the problem (which is incorrect usage of `Html.BeginForm`)?

Comment: OP is trying to send data from view-> controller. My answer shows them how to do that. (i.e. the first method is achieved via a textbox, the other via the model ID). both solutions *get the id parameter value into my controller*

Comment: Your answer misses the point completely. The reason the user is failing to send data from view to controller is because they have misappropriated the parameters of the `Html.BeginForm` method - a basic overview of how action method parameters work (especially a copy/paste from a tutorial) is tangential to the issue and will not help.

Comment: And yet both solutions can be used to solve OP's problem? Their problem may lie with an incorrect overload, however, I was simply displaying that there are other (possibly more efficient) ways of achieving the same thing here.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem, though. The user is attempting to post to a specific controller/action pair so it can be assumed that it is not the current action. The only way to correct that issue is to fix the form by understanding the `BeginForm` method. Even if it *did* solve the problem it would leave the OP no more enlightened than when they started.